# ClickOnce to deploy a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, web, visual-studio-2022, clickonce

I hit the "Publish" button in Visual Studio 2022 and set up everything:

Publishing path: My website repository, where I put all the files (Setup.exe, Publish.html, Application Files, and App.application).
Installation Path: The URL of my website, where users can download the application.
Settings: Everything is set to default.
Sign Manifests: I generate a temporary cert.pfx and use it to sign the manifest.
Configuration: Everything is set to default.
Then, I publish, and my website repository gets the new files. I push everything to DevOps, where the pipelines deliver everything to the actual website. I find my Publish.html page and download the setup.exe file. I manage to download the file, but then I encounter this error:

"The calculated hash for the file App.deps.json is different from the one specified in the manifest."

I've been trying to find a solution. In my Application Files folder, I find all the files—the .manifest, the .deploy, the .deps.json, etc.
When checking with mage, the .manifest file is signed, but the others are not. If I try to sign the other files, mage simply tells me I can't.

On Google or even on StackOverflow, I can't seem to find a precise solution. I've tried recompiling everything, deleting the content of the "bin" folder, and adding some "After Compile" commands, but nothing seems to work. I saw people suggesting to "recreate or updating" the .manifest file, but they never explay how or what to do.

Is ClickOnce just bugged?

I'm so close to publishing my work; please help me.

Comment: Have you tried a bare minimum clickonce deployment?  Create a new WPF without adding extra dependencies, and see if you can get that to work?  Also maybe a simple ClickOnce deployment, to a local folder.  If you can get that to work, then keep adding things to narrow down the problem.  Maybe there is a better way to troubleshoot this, but there can be alot of pieces to troubleshooting ClickOnce and I'm not an expert.

Comment: Have you (not) used the AfterCompile setting on signing?

Comment: Hello! Yes, to both of you. We did create a WPF application with just a blank window and we did try to deploy it on a local folder. And also we used the after compile signing. We did even try to sign everything with mage after the creation of the package

Comment: (sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using ClickOnce to publish a program, "The calculated hash for the file XX is different from the one specified in the manifest." appears. This type of issue can be solved by using the same steps:

1. Go into your project file and delete all the files in the bin.
2. Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties => Security => Uncheck Enable ClickOnce security settings => Save settings

[image]

3. Delete the signature file app.manifest in the project, which is in the Properties directory of the project.
4. Re-check Enable ClickOnce security settings, save the settings, and regenerate the project.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. We have already saw this kind of solution, but using VS 2022 and .NET 7 we do not see the security tab.

Comment: If this is the case, you can try to delete the signature file of the published project and then regenerate the signature.